# Filter angular array by comparing it with another array.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular app I have two arrays of objects that I am displaying. They are both identical types of objects (Questions). One is a List and one is a set of Search Results. In my search results I only want to show the results that are not already in the list. How can I filter out of the search results any results that are already in the List.

In pseudocode it would be something like: for each member of the search result array, display it only if its ID cannot be found in the List array.

Comment: Which part of the pseudo code are you having difficulty with? This looks like you'll need a `for` then `indexOf` (primitive) or a nested `for` (objects).

Comment: Can you show the code of what you have attempted?

Comment: I'm new to JS and Angular. This is trivial in Ruby but I want to do it on the front-end and don't know best practice. Should I use ng-if or ng-show and what is the best way to filter the search results. Should I use $filter and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom filters in angularJS. For your case you can create a similar filter looks like below.

```
var secondArrayAsMap = {};
secondArray.map(function (elementInSecondArray) {
    secondArrayAsMap[elementInSecondArray] = elementInSecondArray;
})
return firstArray.filter(function (elementInFirstArray) {
     return secondArrayAsMap[elementInFirstArray] !== undefined;
});
```

Than in your html you can directly access this filter such as the following:

```
<div ng-repeat=item in filteredItems = (firstArray | yourFilterName:secondArray)>...</div>
```

Comment: should mention when you introduce another library dependency

Comment: You should mention naive `O(n*m)` algorithm that will cause most of mobile phone to drop frames.

Comment: I think OP didn't know how to define filters, thus I just used a naive example. OP may change the algorithm according to its data structure and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This should loop through the array comparing some value, if the value is not in both we add it to a new array that you can then bring back and add to the $scope to show in your view.

**In Your Controller**

```
$scope.data_after_search = //your data
$scope.data = //your data

$scope.newArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < data_after_search.length; i++) 
{
   if ($scope.data_after_search.name != $scope.data.name) {
      //some code
      $scope.newArray += $scope.data_after_search[i];
   }
}
```

This is only a basic example but it should work. 
I used .name because I didn't know what kinds of data you have but you should probably use an id since if 2 things have the same id they should have the same data too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **high order function**, and the **.filter()** method to process your data.

Use a functional approach is a really good choice, make your code more cleaner and reusable. So you can create a function generator, and pass it to your **.filter** method :

```
    var search = [{
      id: 1,
      name:'toto'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name:'titi'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'tata'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: 'john'
    }];

    var list = [{
      id:1,
      name:'toto'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'tata'
    }];

  //Create a function generator to filter our array
  function filterBy(key, filter){
    return function(elm){
      return filter.indexOf(elm[key]) === -1;
    }
  }

  //Use .filter method, by applying high order function and map the list id
  var filtered = search.filter( filterBy('id', list.map(function(e){return e.id}) ) );

  console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not full answer, because it doesn't cover Angular-specific question.

In fact, you are looking for set substraction.[image: set operations]

It can be done in `O(n+m)` time by following code:

```
// returns all elements from arr1, that doesn't have matching ID in arr2
function except(arr1, arr2, propertyName='ID') {
    let exceptIds = new Set(arr2.map(el=>el[propertyName])); // get set of all IDs in array2
    return arr1.filter(el=>!exceptIds.has(el[propertyName]));
}
```

This code use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instance. It can be easily realised in ES5 using object as dictionary and using normal functions.